# Async Await is not working as expected: ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, async-await, react-router

I have this problem where in, user must be redirected to respective dashboards on successful log-in. Say user has accounts in two profiles "p1" and "p2" . After Sign-In success, I am making fetch API to see if user has entries the corresponding profiles.

1)Say if a user has entries in p1, I need to redirect him to "p1" dashboard ;

2) if entries in p2, then redirect him to "p2" dashboard.

3)If no entries are present neither in p1 or p2, then redirect to configuration page where he can make some entries.

4) If in both profile, then user will be asked to select a respective dashboard

Now In my case, the code that I have written is not working as expected. Even though I have no accounts in "p2" but have accounts in "p1" its taking me to configuration page. Can someone help what is wrong in this code?

Note that fetch call just works fine! It gives me array of items. If no items present it returns an empty array

```
// On login 
  handleLogin = async () => {
        // after successful signin
        await Promise.all([
          this.setDashboard("p1"),
          this.setDashboard("p2"),
        ]);
        this.navigateToDashboards();
  };

   setDashboard = async (profile) => {
    let response, value;
    let type = profile;
    if (type === "p1") {
      response = await this.fetchUserAccounts(type);
      value = !!response && response.length ? true : false;
      this.setState({ isP1: value });
    } else {
      response = await this.fetchUserAccounts(type);
      value = !!response && response.length ? true : false;
      this.setState({ isP2: value });
    }
  };

  fetchUserAccounts = async (type) => {
    try {
      let response = await fetch({
        url: "/fetch/entries",
        method: "POST",
        body: {
          profile: type,
        }
      );
      return response.json();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };


    navigateToDashboards = () => {
    let { isP1, isP2 } = this.state;
    if (isP1 && isP2) {
      // CODE FOR PROMPTING WHICH DASHBOARD TO GO
    } else if (!isP1 && !isP2) {
      this.props.history.push("/configpage"); 
    } else if (isP1) {
      this.props.history.push("/p1dashboard");
    } else if (isP2) {
      this.props.history.push("/p2dashboard");
    }
  };
```

Comment: You need to pass an object to fetch. What you have there should be a syntax error. It should be fetch({ url: ..., }). Notice the braces

Comment: The premise seems to be that `fetch()` will throw an error if the server returns a 404.  It does not, afaik.

Comment: @Malvolio issue is not with fetch. I have just given a overall function. Fetch just works fine. Have updated the question

Comment: `setState` is (often) asynchronous. In a react component you would act on `render`. At that moment you can be sure `this.state` has been updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some issues with the code you wrote above and they probably go deeper than we can see in the snippet – why having the logic for the dashboard type on the client-side instead of having it sent from the server?

There is also `cloudType` that is not specified in the `setDashboard` method.

I do not know what you are trying to achieve so I'm guessing – you should probably use `fetchUserAccounts` inside `componentDidMount` and save the response in the state.

I've came up with something like this with one `TODO:` in the code:

```
class X extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      p1: null,
      p2: null,
    };
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const [p1, p2] = await Promise.all([
      this.fetchUserAccounts('p1'),
      this.fetchUserAccounts('p1'),
    ]);
    // NOTE: setState has a second parameter, which is a callback – this way you make sure that the state has been updated – read more here:
    // https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate
    this.setState(s => ({ ...s, p1, p2 }), this.navigateToDashboards);
  }

  fetchUserAccounts = async (type) => {
    try {
      let response = await fetch({
        url: "/fetch/entries",
        method: "POST",
        body: {
          profile: type,
        },
      });
      return response.json();
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };

  navigateToDashboards = () => {
    const { history } = this.props;
    const { p1, p2 } = this.state;
    // TODO: Implement your logic how you decide 
    if (isP1 && isP2) {
      // CODE FOR PROMPTING WHICH DASHBOARD TO GO
      return;
    }
    if (isP1) return history.push('/p1dashboard');
    if (isP2) return history.push('/p2dashboard');
    return history.push('/configpage');
  }
}
```

If this does not work at least have a look at the code structure. There are places where you do not require the `else` statement. Use the function version of the `setState`. Make use of object/array desctrucuring. You should also probably read about what is `false` and `true` in the JS world based on the `!!response && response.length ? true : false;` lines – or maybe there is something I'm missing out here.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is you're using `async / await` wrong.

`await` works on promises- you give it a promise, and it waits for it to resolve / reject. If you do not give it a promise- its like passing it an immediately resolved promise.

Your `setDashboard` function does not reutrn a promise, so what happens is that this code:

```
await Promise.all([
          this.setDashboard("p1"),
          this.setDashboard("p2"),
        ]);
```

actually resolves immediately, but the `setDashboard` functions are not executed up until `this.navigateToDashboards();`. why? because they are defined as async, which puts them in event loop. Then comes in the `await`, but it immediately resolves as the functions inside does not return a promise (well, it does, because it is async, but its like writing `return promise.resolve()` as the first line- so the `await` does nothing only placing the function in event loop)- and the code continues to execute in synchronous fashion until it reaches the end of the function (e.g- executing `this.navigateToDashboards();`, and only then goes to event loop and execute the `setDashboards` functions.

On the same subject, `response = await this.fetchUserAccounts(type);` line also has redundant await, because `fetchUserAccounts()` does not return a promise.

To correctly use async / await- make sure your `async` function return a promise, for example:

```
setDashboard = async (profile) => {
 return new Promise( resolve, reject => {
    let response, value;
    let type = profile;
    if (type === "p1") {
      response = await this.fetchUserAccounts(type);
      value = !!response && response.length ? true : false;
      this.setState({ isP1: value });
      resolve();
    } else {
      response = await this.fetchUserAccounts(cloudType);
      value = !!response && response.length ? true : false;
      this.setState({ isP2: value });
      resolve();
    }
  })
};
```

as for fetchUserAccount:

```
fetchUserAccounts = async (type) => {
  return new Promise( resolve, reject => {
    try {
      let response = await fetch({
        url: "/fetch/entries",
        method: "POST",
        body: {
          profile: type,
        }
      );
      resolve(response.json());
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      reject(error);
    }
  }
};
```

Notice that you will now have to handle promise rejections using `.catch`, otherwise you'll get `unhandled promise rejection error`.

Comment: Some things wrong in here.  For example, `setDashboard()` is declared `async`, therefore it always returns a promise - automatically.  Your additional wrapping it in a promise is completely unnecessary and considered an anti-pattern.  Same for `fetchUserAccounts()`.  Much of this answer is just wrong.

Comment: @jfriend00 it returns a promise, like I wrote, but since there is no "return" statement it automatically resolves the promise and you can't control over when it will. if `fetchUserAccounts` there is a return- but only partial, so same thing happens there. it also makes sense, since it redirects him to configuration page as if there is no profile type is updated in state before it reaches `fetchUserAccounts`. If your async function does not return either a promise or return anything at all - it will be resolved immediately because there is nothing for the `await` to wait for.

Comment: As `async` function will resolve its promise AFTER all the `await` statements in the function are done and then when the function is done executing code after the last `await`.  Since there's no `return` statement, the resolved value of the promise will be `undefined`, but the promise still resolves properly with the appropriate timing.  I'm not saying the OP's code is perfect, but your description of what needs to be done is just wrong.  You don't need to manually return a promise from an `async` function.